# Is it possible to recompile jar targeting different version?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I want to use a jar in my Android application which is compiled with **Maven**.
The problem is that the jar is compiled targeting 1.8 Java, when Android needs 1.7 or lower.

I have the jar file along with source files. Below you can see the directory of the source files of the library:

```
C:.
|   pom.xml
|   sonar-project.properties
|   
+---.sonar
|   \---.sonartmp
|       \---caches
+---src
|   +---main
|   |   +---java
|   |   |   \---(folder with source java files)
|   |   |                       
|   |   \---resources
|   |           logback.xml
|   |           
|   \---test
|       \---(folder with java files)
|                               
\---target
    |   OLDJAR.jar
    |   
    +---classes
    |   |   .netbeans_automatic_build
    |   |   logback.xml
    |   |   
    |   \---(folder with class files)
    |                       
    +---generated-sources
    |   +---annotations
    |   \---test-annotations
    +---javadoc-bundle-options
    |       javadoc-options-javadoc-resources.xml
    |       package-list
    |       
    +---maven-archiver
    |       pom.properties
    |       
    +---site
    |   \---(folder with Htmls)
    |                               
    \---test-classes
        |   .netbeans_automatic_build
        |   
        \---(class files)
```

Since I am new to Maven, I would really appreciate some help here. How can I make a new jar targeting this time 1.7 version?

I have modified the pom.xml file to target 1.7:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I want to know what is the proper way to recompile this into a jar. I tried 
`mvn clean install` but I got some test failures. Am I missing something?

EDIT: When I try `mvn clean install` I get the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.677 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-23T14:20:25+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 23M/400M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project Project: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Thanks..

Comment: Your approach seems fine. *I got some test failures* isn't very specific, could be more precise?

Comment: If you aren't worried about the test failures, you can run `mvn clean install -DskipTests`. Did you get the same test failures under 1.8? Downgrading the language version can obviously cause problems

Comment: @vikingsteve I did not think of that. Could it be the change of the version that causes the test failures? I downloaded the 1.8 compiled version of the jar so I guess that there were no test failures..

Comment: Yes, most definitely. Try to revert it to 1.8 temporarily, build with tests, and let us know if it builds green. In this way you can isolate the failures to language level. Zavael's answer explains in nice detail.

Comment: @vikingsteve even with 1.8 I get errors: 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) on project: There are test failures.
[ERROR] Please refer to surefire-reports for the individual test results.
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: Right, well you really should find why the tests are failing and get a clean build before continuing, as per Zavael's anwser.

Answer (score 3):

If tests fails you **should look why**. It can be that in the source code, there are features used from java 8, that are not present in java 7, like lambda expressions, streams, new DateTime api etc.

You can always try to compile the source code without running the tests as is described here [Maven - Skipping tests](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-surefire-plugin-2.12.4/examples/skipping-test.html) but I dont recommend it.

Comment: You are right: Tests are there to test the quality of software, and they should be respected. But do not worry about using language features not present in your compiler/JRE's version: They would fail _at compile time_, even if tests are turned off.

Comment: yes, i am almost sure that if new features were used in tests, they will be used in app source code too, therefore I dont recomend skipping tests

Comment: I tried skipping the tests to see if jar is created anyway but it was not. Is it possible that there were not test failures when oldjar was built but there are now?

Comment: @TinaLooke most likely the new features of the java 8 (i.ei 1.8 source) are the main cause of tests failures and compile failure too. You should examine the failures to move on in identifying the problem.

Comment: @Zavael I tried to compile with java 8 and I still get errors. Is this possible? Maybe I am missing something else? Hidden dependencies etc?

Comment: @TinaLooke I would look before the "[INFO] BUILD FAILURE [ERROR] Failed to execute goal ..." part of output and see what is causing the error. It should be written right before that

Comment: @Zavael I can see that there some different outputs than expected and that is why there is test failure. What baffles me is that how did this become a jar in the first place since there test failures and no new jar file is created for me? I cannot think of anything else I could do. Can I use the already created jar? (Since it was created, I guess there were no test failures?)

Comment: @TinaLooke I have no knowledge about android development, but i dont think that jar compiled for jre 8 is runnable under jre 7, but I can be wrong

Comment: @Zavael Besides android, if oldjar exists, why I cannot remake it using mvn clean install? I mean without editing pom.xml file.

Comment: @TinaLooke as I understand - because there are language differencies between java 7 and 8 as are differencies in jre 7 and 8. JRE is responsible for running java application, therefore you cannot run java 8 application on jre7, but you can run java 7 application on jre8. Java is compatible with older versions, but not with future versions. Look for some links about JVM vs JRE

Comment: @TinaLooke oldjar was maybe created before new source codes were added, only author of the app knows. If you are not capable to resolve the problems, try to contact the author.

Answer (score 2):

You should not ignore test failures. However, if you want to check if there are other problems beside the test failures, you can temporarily suppress testing by supplying *-Dmaven.test.skip=true* to maven.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to add two *profiles* to your pom: One for compiling in 1.7 and the other for 1.8. Example:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
    ...
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jdk1.7</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>jdk1.8</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Then, you have to chose one of them when invoking to Maven. From commandline, it is:

```
mvn -P jdk1.8 clean install
```

From a development environment (like Eclipse), there is usually a text field to specify the selected profiles.

See the official [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

And, of corse, I encourage you not to ignore the test results.